# Jasper creating Table of Content with pages in simple report

Tags: jasper-reports

I created a report with Jaspersoft and fill it from my Spring Boot backend. Since I am new to this, I want to have it in a easy way.

The report is consisting only of one .jrxml file, because I didn´t manage to use anyhting else with my Spring Boot backend.

My problem is, that I want to have a table of contents in the beginning, but I don´t manage to put the page numbers of the headlines into the ToC. The headlines itself are static but I want to know on which page they are.

Is it somehow possible to go to the headlines and put the current page into a variable, which I will reference in the ToC? Or is there any other easy solution? "Countless" youtube tutorials didn´t help me.